# Shell Scripting Function question

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have this code snippet I am working on for a small project I am doing:

```
echo "Please enter SUID: ";
read $uid

uid_Assoc(){
        arg1=$1
        echo $1;
}

uid_Assoc
```

Now to start, I would like this to prompt for a string and read the string. From there I would like to pass that string as an argument and echo it out. But I am not sure how to pass the string off as a parameter. When I attempt to do something like:

```
uid_Assoc($uid)
```

It throws a syntax error (I figured that would be incorrect anyways). Are there any suggestions on how to do this?

UPDATE: I also tried re-arranging the code a bit to look like this:

```
function uid_Assoc(){
        arg1=$1
        echo $1;
}
echo "Please enter SUID: ";
read $uid
uid_Assoc $uid
```

But that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your script as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter SUID: ";
read uid

uid_Assoc () {
        arg1="$1"
        echo "$1"
        echo "$arg1"
}

uid_Assoc "$uid"
```

You just need to remove the `$` prefix before uid in the `read` call.

Answer (score 4):

The `read` command takes a variable **name**, so remove the sigil:

```
read uid
```

What you are doing, is this: sending the contents of the uid variable as the variable name for the read command. Since this value is currently empty, you have

```
echo "a prompt: "
read
```

That is valid bash code. The default variable name for a "bald" read command is `REPLY`

Given your code, here is a mild rewrite:

```
function uid_Assoc {
        local arg1=$1
        echo "$arg1";
}

read -p "Please enter SUID: " uid
uid_Assoc "$uid"
```

Notes:

- you don't need both the `function` keyword and the `()` syntax, choose one or the other (my opinion only)
- localize variables in functions to limit their scope
- use the `-p` option to read
- **always** quote referenced variables (you never know how many spaces the user will type), unless you know *why* you need to leave a variable unquoted.

Comment: I tried that but did not get an echo of the string in the method. It just shows a blank..

Comment: You tried what, exactly?